# Einstein Activity Capture is taking long time to reset

Tags: salesforce, admin

I have set Einstein Activity Capture in my sandbox (unlimited edition), I haven't connected any accounts to it.

I wanted to change from Google suite to microsoft exchange, so I reset the Einstein Activity Capture.
It is still resetting. it's been more than 6 hours. How much time it may take to complete.

Einstein Activity Capture is resetting for a long time.